# How to install JsHint for Rhino and vim on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: javascript, vim, rhino, jshint

How do I install JSHint on Ubuntu 11.10?

I am reading guides on how to setup vim for javascript.  I want to use rhino and vim.

I have used vundle to install jshint.vim.  The resources I am using:

[Vim as a Javascript Ide](http://www.brankovukelic.com/post/2091037293/turn-vim-into-powerful-javascript-editor)
and [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/platforms/)

I have also installed syntastic [Syntastic Github](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/#readme)

Comment: Found this guide here http://technotales.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/node-jslint-and-vim/   and also this interactive node configure script http://apptob.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more easier to use node/npm to install jshint:

1. grab [nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) from github
2. `sudo nave usemain latest`
3. npm install jshint

Comment: I downloaded nave from github and then ran the command chmod +x nave.sh && sudo ./nave.sh but when I go to use sudo nave usemain latest it is still saying nave doesn't exist.           sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/nave$ sudo nave usemain latest
sudo: nave: command not found

Comment: You still need to cd to where you saved nave.sh and `sudo ./nave.sh usemain latest`. Or you can `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/sbin/nave /path/to/nave.sh` then you can do `sudo nave` wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

jshint is strongly recommended to be installed globally:

Logged in as root:

```
npm install -g jshint
```

or with sudo:

```
sudo npm install -g jshint
```

This enables other programs to use it (like editors).

Answer (score 0):

### How to install JSHint on Ubuntu 12.10

**Install nodejs, npm and jshint:**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g jshint
```

**Then run it on commandline:**

```
jshint your_js_file.js
```

**Which prints:**

```
js.js: line 4, col 21, Use '===' to compare with '0'.
js.js: line 24, col 2, Missing semicolon.
2 errors
```

Prepare to get your feelings hurt because your javascript file has hundreds of things wrong with it.